# limit for an oscillating function $\sin\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: limits

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}   \frac{\sin(x\sin\frac{1}{x})}{x\sin\frac{1}{x}}$ 
Since $\lim x\sin\frac{1}{x} = 0$, and $\lim \frac{\sin x}{x} = 0$, final answer should be $1$.

Is the answer $1$ or it does not exist?

Comment: Use LaTeX formatting!
Answer $1$ seems good for me.

Comment: You are right, and oscillations do no matter. (The argument of $\sin x/x$ can tend to zero the way it likes.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$$

Comment: What is $\bigodot$ mean?

Comment: @S.C.B.: quodlibet.

Comment: @quodlibet = Whatever you want, but of course not 0. But anything that converges to zero is ok.

Comment: Since $\frac{\sin(x\sin\frac{1}{x})}{x\sin\frac{1}{x}}$ is not defined in a neighborhood of $0$ (or even in a one-sided neighborhood of $0),$ it seems to me that the limit does not exist (as is ordinarily defined).